# What is wrong with #define myptr int *?

Tags: c++, macros

Here is a small snippet of code :

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

#define myptr int *

int main(){
    myptr p,q;
    int c;
    p = &c;
    q = &c;
    c = 2;
    cout<<c<<endl;
    cout<<*p<<endl;
    cout<<*q<<endl;

    return 0;
}
```

`p` has type `int*` while `q` has type `int`. Why is this happening ?

Comment: #define is "Almost" like a "find and replace" in the editor..but not interchangeable.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After the macro substitution, `myptr p,q;` becomes

```
int *p,q;
```

It's a common mistake to think the type of `q` is `int*`, but actually it's `int`.

What you need is `typedef`:

```
typedef int* myptr;
```

Answer (score 5):

The `*` binds to the variable, not the type. You need to repeat it for every declaration on the line.

A typedef would work the way you expect:

```
typedef int * myptr;
```

Answer (score 4):

A define is just a simple replacement macro.  If you replace `myptr` with `int *`, just like the preprocessor will do, you will see why `q` is just an `int`:

```
int *p,q;
```

For what you are attempting, you need to use a `typedef`instead:

```
typedef int* myptr;
```

Answer (score 0):

If still you wish to use `myptr`, you can do it like this::

```
myptr p ;
myptr q ;
```

But its better to use `typedef`